# How to bind the label in GridView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using Gridview to display my details

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Details" runat="server" Text="Remarks"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="remarks" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now from the backend c# i am fetching from database and displaying

```
var regiondata = (from rm in db.RegionMasters select new { rm.regionName,rm.remarks,rm.regionId }).ToList();
          if (regiondata.Count > 0)
          {
            foreach (var region in regiondata)
            {                    
                string z = region.remarks.ToString().Substring(0, 5);    
                ((Label)gvDetails.FindControl("remarks")).Text = z.ToString();    
                gvDetails.DataSource = region;
                gvDetails.DataBind();

             }

           }
```

so to display in the label thats inside the gridview i am using ((Label)gvDetails.FindControl("remarks")).Text = z.ToString(); but it keeps showing me "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: where did you bind your `label` ? in `OnItemDataBound` or something ?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField> 
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Details" runat="server" Text="Remarks"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                
                <asp:Label ID="remarks" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField> i am using templatefield

Comment: no no , I mean where did you write above C# code , and I think you should check your retrieved list data using break-point . Are they correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the grid like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Details" runat="server" Text="Remarks"></asp:Label>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="remarks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("remarks").ToString().Substring(0,5) %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And C# code.

```
var regiondata = (from rm in db.RegionMasters select new { rm.regionName,rm.remarks,rm.regionId }).ToList();
if (regiondata.Count > 0)
{              
     gvDetails.DataSource = regiondata;
     gvDetails.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find it like this

```
      protected void grdQuestionSet_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType.Equals(GridItemType.Item))
            //can also check if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
            {
             Label yourlabel= (e.Item.FindControl("labelId") as Label);
             //bind your label to data here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Details" runat="server" Text="Remarks"></asp:Label>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="remarks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("remarks")'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:GridView>

var regiondata = (from rm in db.RegionMasters select new {       rm.regionName,rm.remarks,rm.regionId }).ToList();
      if (regiondata.Count > 0)
      {
           gvDetails.DataSource = regiondata;
           gvDetails.DataBind();
       }
```